# generate a png from a given area of pixels on the screen

Tags: javascript, image, png, client-side

I know that it's possible to generate an image from a canvas element with javascript, but what if you have a given area (div's and images only) and you want to take that given area and make it a png for someone to download client side?

is this even possible with javascript, if not with js, then is it possible at all with other languages?

perhaps some way of automatically taking a screenshot and cropping to the right size programmatically?
I have no idea...
thanks :)

Comment: There is an awesome project called `html2canvas` by Niklas von Hertzen that probably suits your needs.

Comment: whoa, that's pretty awesome. I'll see if it works for my purposes.

Comment: the big problem is lack of support for certain properties, here's a link to what i was thinking about using it for: http://reveriesrefined.com/myftp/face/

Comment: I meant to provide a hyperlink but got distracted - sorry! So here it is: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: No worries, I just googled it like a big boy.

Comment: http://www.reveriesrefined.com/myftp/face/
     this is what I want to use it for.

It's an interactive and animated face, so I want people to be able to click a button and save a picture of their face onto their device. There will be more features added to blockface in the future, but this is just a starting point.